# Conditional query if first query didn't find anything?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to fetch a field from one table, and if its not there, try to fetch it from another table
so

```
 select printer_id from all_printers where printer_name ='printer1'
```

If its there - return it, if its not there

```
select printer_id from new_printers where printer_name ='printer1'
```

Since i am writing a web application I would like to minimize the code and DB  hits, i would like to know if there is a way to do this in a single query without hitting both query if its not necessary.

left join will work, but the tables are huge (millions of records), and I don't want it to hit both of them if not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
with ap as (
      select printer_id from all_printers where printer_name = 'printer1'
     )
select printer_id
from ap
union all
select printer_id
from new_printers np
where not exists (select 1 from ap)
```

Comment: Great! will this save the priority? all_printers  will be executed first?

Comment: @user648026 . . .  Yes, it saves the priority.

Comment: Gordon, how come we don't need filter on [from new_printers np]?   like from new_printers np where printer_name = 'printer1'?

Comment: @user648026 . . . There is a filter; it is not in the original list.